# use asp.net serverside validation in angular js?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, validation

I am developing an angular js app. with a asp.net web api server. The validation is model based like:

```
  [Required]
  public int ID { get; set; } 

  [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
  public string name { get; set; }

  [Range(15, 100)]
  public int age { get; set; }
```

I would like to implement the same validation rules on the clientside ie in my angular code. Is there an existing directive that can do this?

Comment: Take a look at this validation module http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at these post https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project - https://github.com/alisabzevari/ngval